# How to enable Edit Tool handles when Middle Mouse is Pan?

Tags: tools, mouse

Something about the way I've created a quite 3ds Max like navigation system in 3.6 has meant that I can't operate the handles of tools like Shrink/Fatten.

Is there a setting that enables some other means of operating these handle based tools?

Comment: Since we have no idea how you've created your "3ds Max like navigation" there's no way we can answer that question, however you can use the normal Alt-S hotkey for shrink/fatten rather than selecting the tool icons. If you hover over the icon you should get a popup which shows the shortcut key.

Comment: It's not the shortcut that's the problem. It's that the handles aren't at all selectable to edit/use the Shrink/Fatten tool once it's activated. This seems to be the case with all handle tools, once I've set the mouse to whatever I've set it to, and there's no where to manually enter/adjust/edit the power/usage of these handle based tools other than with the mouse... that's not working to grab those handles. And I don't know what I've done to make this not work, or how there could be only one way to use these tools and a way to block their operation.

Comment: Dragging the handles with the mouse is the only way to use those gizmo tools as far as I know apart of course from the settings menu which appears in the bottom left of the screen when they're active. To be honest I always use shortcut hotkeys rather than the toolbar icons except occasionally for animating. The section on keymaps in the Blender manual is [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/preferences/keymap.html#keymap).